# Generate random value at interval of 5 Sec in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, random, setinterval

Can anyone tell me how to generate random value between `0 and 100` in an interval of `5 seconds`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With help from

- [`Math.random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random),
- [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval)

```js
function setRandom() {
    document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = Math.random() * 101 | 0;
}
setRandom();
setInterval(setRandom, 5000);
```

```html
<div id="out"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks @nina :)) 
It worked

Answer (score 2):

```
function randomIntFromInterval(min,max)
{
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);
}

var randomNum = 0;

setInterval(function () {
    randomNum = randomIntFromInterval(0, 100);
}, 5000)
```

Comment: Thanks @ilian6806 :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, Thanks for the repliy @nina-scholz @ilian6806 .

```
var random = 0;
random = randomizator(0,100);
function randomizator(a,b)
{
return Math.floor(Math.random()*b) + a;
}
```

I used another function to handle my Interval.